# Memory allocation of struct member variables

Tags: c

I am new to C. I have these two files set up in this way.
I do not fully understand how I am able to assign values in the Item array without dynamically allocating memory.
The line Collection c; places all fields on the stack, so is that why I can directly set array members?

```
//collection.c
typedef struct {
   uint32 price;
   uint32 itemId;
} Item;

typedef struct {
    Item item[MAX_SIZE];   
    uint32 name;
} Collection;

void function(Collection * ptr)
{
    int i;
    uint32 id = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        ptr->item[i].price = 10;
        ptr->item[i].itemId = id;
        id++;
    }
}
//collection_main.c

Collection c; //global struct variable 
//calls function in collection.c
function(&c);
```

Comment: As written, whatever calls `function(Collection *ptr);` has to supply a pointer to a `Collection` struct that already exists. It can exist in any type of storage (stack, heap, dynamically allocated, etc), but it must already exist. One often has a line at the start of such a function to check that the passed pointer is not null...

Comment: @bazza it does exist, and the pointer is supplied (in the abbreviated code). The function assigns values to an array which does not need dynamic memory allocation because the static struct `Collection c` already contains an array of another `struct` type `Item`. Aside: please use the standard type `uint32_t` in `stdint.h` and not invent your own.

Comment: Guys explained to you whats the difference, ill just add that you should (if possible) avoid dynamic memory allocation. Its more error-prone and harder to use than automatic variables.

Comment: *"The line Collection c; places all fields on the stack"* - the comment says it's a global variable, so I am presuming it's not defined inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not fully understand how I am able to assign values in the Item array without dynamically allocating memory.

First, as you are new to C, be aware of a potential issue with passing C functions pointers (which is quite reasonable, BTW).  Unless you can *guarantee* that your calling code will always pass a valid pointer you need to check that pointer value in the function as best you can.  That will typically amount to checking for a non-null pointer like this :

```
if ( ptr == NULL )
    return <whatever to signal an error> ;
```

In this case you did allocate memory, because you created a `Collection` variable and that contains allocated space for the required fields.

> The line `Collection c;` places all fields on the stack,

If it's in a function it will (typically) allocate space on that function's [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#STACK-FRAME), which you should logically view as a separate area that the calling code cannot access.  Make no assumptions about the layout of the stack.  A very typical bug is to try and return a pointer to an item declared inside a function, and even supposedly experienced programmers have been known to do it.

Another potential bug in passing a pointer to a function is trying to access beyond the limits of the space allocated and pointed to.  This can do things like corrupt other variables or even crash code.  Your own code is correctly using the declared constant size of the array, so no problem.

If you do this outside of a function (which is possible), you would be using space reserved by the OS for these type of variables.  That may not be on the stack but elsewhere.  The OS gets that information from the compiled code file.

> so is that why I can directly set array members ?

C code (and the executable binary that's produced by the compiler) does not care or check whether the pointers you pass are valid or not.  So it's possible to pass a bad pointer to a C function and cause chaos.

In this case you did allocate all the required valid memory when you declared the variable and you passed a pointer to that variable.  So no problem.

> Dynamic memory allocation

It is more usual to consider explicit allocation using the `malloc()` family of functions as *dynamic allocation*.  Allocations for local and global variables may be dynamic in the sense that they can happen at runtime but the allocation and deallocation are not the responsibility of the programmer to explicitly control so you do not generally need to think about these as part of dynamic memory allocation.

A minor point to close :

```
uint32 name ;
```

I'd consider this a bad choice of field name.  Using "name" implies a string, whereas you probably mean a string id from e.g. an array.  So try something like :

```
uint32 nameid ;
```

instead.

You'd be surprised how many coding problems crop up in a production environment simply because of a poor choice of variable name.  Make them informative if possible and practical.

This is just a good coding habit to get into, IMO.